# Determine if there is any interactive user on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, service

From a service running on a Windows 7 machine, I'd like to be able to determine if there is any interactive user logged on AND active.  This should count for users that are logged on locally or via remote-desktop.  If a user is logged on locally and locks their machine, that would be considered inactive.

Comment: So what's the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

- Enumerate the sessions with `WTSEnumerateSessions`. This gives you a list of session IDs.
- Call `WTSQuerySessionInformation` for each session ID. Specify `WTSSessionInfoEx` for the `WTSInfoClass` parameter. This gives you a `WTSINFOEX` struct.
- Inside that is a `WTSINFOEX_LEVEL1` struct. From that you can read the session state and check for the session being locked by looking for `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK` in the session flags.